# Добавление картинки и тега a href в div c помощью Javascript

Tags: javascript

Немогу догодаться как добавить с помощью javascript'a линк который должен быть прикреплен к картинке. Картинку наимплементировал, немогу догадаться как добавить к картинке tag a. Спасибо

```
var img = new Image();
var div = document.getElementById('left_column');

img.onload = function() {
  div.appendChild(img);
};

img.src ='https://cdn.deliverio.cz/sampure_temp/img/PBA.jpg';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var img = new Image();

var link = document.createElement("a");
img.src ='https://cdn.deliverio.cz/sampure_temp/img/PBA.jpg';
link.href= "#";

link.appendChild(img);
var div = document.getElementById('left_column');

img.onload = function() {
  div.appendChild(link);
};
```

```html
<div id="left_column"></div>
```

Comment: Немного не правильно поняли вопрос? `немогу догадаться как добавить к картинке tag a`. А событие `onload` асинхронное, без разницы до или после метода вставлять `img.src = ''`

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, внимательно!!!

Comment: Тогда прошу прощения :)))

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, а вообще странно, у меня почему-то сразу не выполнился код, когда `img.src = ''` стоял после `onload`

Comment: а что должно было выполнится? грузить нечего :) ну это если пусто, а так, асинхронный код сработает 100% после всего остального кода, т.к. имеет постоянную задержку, т.е. он выполняется не в момент выполнения

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, картинка не отображалась. Видимо какие-то технические проблемы) js bin последнее время заедает у меня

Answer (score 1):

```js
var img = new Image();
var div = document.getElementById('left_column');

img.onload = function() {
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = this.src;
  link.appendChild(img);
  div.appendChild(link);
};

img.src ='https://cdn.deliverio.cz/sampure_temp/img/PBA.jpg';
```

```html
<div id="left_column"></div>
```